# Create an array from an nth term formula with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a randomly generated nth term formula in the format `2n^2` or `2n`.

I was wondering if you could create a function that creates an array with the first 5 digits of the sequence defined by the randomly generated nth term?

Thanks for any help in advance.

P.S. For those who don't know, `^2` means squared.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed! ...where did you get stuck when you tried this, what didn't work, how did it go wrong..?

Comment: Please show what you're tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code providing service.

Comment: I was getting stuck with the working out of the values

Comment: @AndréDion I know that you have to do a `for loop` with 5 iterations and work out the formula and then push that to an array but I don't know how to work out the values of the formula.

Comment: Why were you working out the values, that's the job of the script as written isn't it? Also where does `n` start? Should n[1] by the square of n[0], or is it a sequence of five consecutive numbers, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5..?

Comment: I was getting stuck figuring out how to get the script to figure out the values.

Comment: It is a sequence of 5 consecutive numbers.

Comment: So the output would be, given a start of `1`: `1`,`4`, `9`, `16`, `25`?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple `for` loop:

```js
function calculateIt(start, end) {
  // store the values
  var ret = [];

  // loop from start to end
  for (var i = start; i < end; ++i) {
    // calculate value and push to array
    ret.push(2 * Math.pow(i, 2));
  }

  // return array
  return ret;
}

console.log(calculateIt(0, 10).join(", "));
console.log(calculateIt(5, 8).join(", "));
```

Or:

```js
function calculateIt(start, end) {
  // create an array of the length we want, get the keys (indexs), convert to array, use map to get a new array
  return [...Array(end).keys()].splice(start).map(n => 2 * Math.pow(n, 2));
}

console.log(calculateIt(0, 10).join(", "));
console.log(calculateIt(5, 7).join(", "));
```

Comment: Thanks. Not a complete answer but I will use it.

Comment: I think I see the issue now. What do you mean by "randomly generated nth term"? Where will the equation come from?

Comment: It sounds like you want to convert an equation like `2n^2` or `n^2`, or `3+n^3 / n` into something JavaScript can use. This can get complicated depending on how complex the equation can be because you'll have to write a function to convert the string function input into a JavaScript function and you'll have to know all the situations you'll need to account for like power, divisor, summation, etc..

Comment: Sounds like you want an equation parser. http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html